# How to make wind only affect one object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I am currently having some trouble with Blender right now (cycles). I have created a plane with a cloth simulation and a wind to move the plane.
[image]
I wanted to add this with the rest of my project I am working on, but when I add the wind and plane to my rainy scene, it completely changes the rain.
[image]
I created the rain with a particle simulator, and it is animated. I want to have the wind only affect the plane, but not the rain. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview:

As far as I can see, your rain is made by using **Particle System**, so you will need to turn off **Wind** under **Field Weights** for it or for any other object you don't want to be affected by this **Force Field**.

[image: final]

Answer (score -1):

This really saved me I’m trying to make a rocket taking off on grass and it was inverting my grass particles on the wrong side of the plane.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/157979)